# Get font information from FormattedText in WPF

Tags: wpf, fonts

I have FormattedText object, how can retrieve it fonts information like what range has which font like . ObjFormattedText.GetFontSize(istartIndex,iendIndex). ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [FormattedText members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext_members.aspx) it doesnt seem like that information is available after formatting.

The only way i know to format text and still retrieve the information is to take a different approach and use the [TextFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textformatting.textformatter.aspx) instead, though this can be tricky. You have to implement several interfaces, and it is not always clear what exactly is expected of your implementation. Even then it is not trivial to retreive the required information, but at least it is possible.